# running a mysql script generated from workbench using mysql commandline

Tags: mysql

i have built my schema as an EER, generated the script from foward Engineer and i now want to run the same script on another computer, so as to create the database without the workbench but via the commandline using. this script. and am getting an error2. 'failed to open file' please help.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details. What is the structure of your file ? What is the command line you are using ? What OS are you using ? etc.

Comment: using windows7. the mysql command line. the file is a .sql generated from mysql workbench EER using.

Comment: « the mysql command line » ... ok. But what did you type ?